# How to Permanently disable a JMS queue on Jboss Application Server 3.2.7

Tags: jboss, jms

I have a JMS queue on a Jboss application server (3.2.7) that I want to permanently disable (just the queue, not the app server as whole).

Through the JMX console I can find the queue (under `jboss.mq.destination`) and stop it.
But the JBoss server gets restarted every night and thus restarts the queue.

From the documentation I have seen, I should be able to just remove the listing for the JMS queue in file jbossmq-destinations-service.xml which is located in
`jboss-3.2.7\server\default\deploy\jms`

This was the only file location of this file that had the correct queue listing in.

I have removed it (the listing for the queue) and restarted the application server. but the queue still continues to startup...

What step am I missing?
Do I need to redeploy something for this change to take effect?

Also, for the queue info page it has a state setting of 3, but no way to change this, is this some sort of persistence setting, as the messages do get persisted to an integrated Hypersonic database, as I understand it.